# Openstreetmap(OSM) not loading with proxy server in QT4

Tags: qt, openstreetmap

I am using QT4 to create application using openstreetmap(OSM) promoted in one of the widget...Map loads fine when system is connected to internet directly without proxy server....But fails to load the map when connected through proxy server.....

But this project works fine when opened with QT5(proxy/direct connection method)....

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I think you need to have a quick read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to give us some more information so that we can help you.

Comment: Definitely not related to OpenStreetMap.

Answer (score 0):

To get an connection through a proxy you have to set [`QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkproxy.html#details) for your application.